# Microsoft.Interop.Excel can't read cell value

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I wrote a small method that will give me the headers of a table in excel:

```
private List<string> GetCurrentHeaders(int headerRow, Excel.Worksheet ws)
{
    //List where specific values get saved if they exist
    List<string> headers = new List<string>();
    //List of all the values that need to exist as headers
    var headerlist = columnName.GetAllValues();

    for (int i = 0; i < headerlist.Count; i++)
    {
        //GetData() is a Method that outputs the Data from a cell.
        //headerRow is defining one row under the row I actually need, therefore -1 )
        string header = GetData(i + 1, headerRow - 1, ws);

        if (headerlist.Contains(header) && !headers.Contains(header))
        {
            headers.Add(header);
        }
    }

    return headers;
}
```

Now I got an Excel-table, where the first value I need is in cell A11 (or Row 11, Column 1).

When I set a breakpoint after `string header = GetData(i + 1, headerRow - 1, ws);`, where `i+1 = 1` and `headerRow - 1 = 11`, I can see that the value he read is empty, which is not the case.

The GetData-Method just does one simple thing:

```
public string GetData(int row, int col, Excel.Worksheet ws)
{
    string val = "";

    val = Convert.ToString(ws.Cells[row, col].Value) != null 
        ? ws.Cells[row, col].Value.ToString() :  "";

    val = val.Replace("\n", " ");

    return val;
}
```

I don't get why this can't get me the value I need, while it works on every other excel table too. The excel itself is no different from the others. It's file extension is .xls, the data is in the same layout as in the other tables, etc

Comment: What are the `columnName` and `coords` objects in this methods? private variables of a container class?

Comment: coords was a mistake. I overloaded the GetData Method, and simplified it here and forgot to change that part. columnNames is an object that contains every column-name/header that I need. The method needs to check if some of these headers are missing and tells me which one

Comment: And just to be clear, by table you mean what is formally known in Excel as a table (Menu → Insert → Table)? or do you mean just a range that contains data with headers in the form of a table?

Comment: Yeah, it's just an excel-range, with some column-names and the data below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few steps to getting this right. You need to know the dimensions of your table to know where the headers are. Your method hast two ways of knowing this: 1) passing the table `Range` to the method, or 2) giving the coordinates of a cell within the table (usually the top-left cell) and trusting the `CurrentRegion` property to do the job for you. The most reliable way would be the first as you will be explicitly telling the method where to look, but it'll require the consumer to figure out the address which isn't always straightforward. The `CurrentRegion` approach works fine too but note that if you have an empty column within your table range, it will only address until that empty column. Having said all that, you could have the following:

```
List<string> GetHeaders(Worksheet worksheet, int row, int column)
    {
        Range currentRegion = worksheet.Cells[row, column].CurrentRegion;
        Range headersRow = currentRegion.Rows[1];
        var headers = headersRow
            .Cast<Range>() // We cast so we can use LINQ
            .Select(c => c.Text is DBNull ? null : c.Text as string) //The null value of c.Text is not null but DBNull
            .ToList();
        return headers;
    }
```

Then you can simply test if you're missing headers. The following code assumes the `ActiveCell` is a cell within the table `Range`, but you can change that easily to address a specific cell.

```
List<string> GetMissingHeaders(List<string> expectedHeaders)
{
    var worksheet = App.ActiveSheet; //App is your Excel application
    Range activeCell = worksheet.ActiveCell;
    var headers = GetHeaders(worksheet, activeCell.Row, activeCell.Column);
    return expectedHeaders.Where(h => headers.Any(i => i == h) == false).ToList();
}
```

Comment: @DudeWhoWantsToLearn Does this help you?